# How to add horizontal scrolling for react-native-chart-kit StackedBarChart?

Tags: react-native, react-native-chart-kit

I'm looking forward to create horizontally scrollable StackedBarChart with react-native-chart-kit. Is it possible to create such chart with this package and how?

Comment: Did you try to wrap the chart inside a ScrollView with horizontal={true} as prop ? The charts are created with SVGs, you could also modify the root svg and ad panning to it with react native gesture handler for instance

Comment: @Kape I did but it leads to moving axis values/titles too. So I guess I need built-in feature for that.

Comment: Did you get a success with this?

Answer (score 3):

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true}> <BarChart style={graphStyle} chartConfig={chartConfig} verticalLabelRotation={30} /> `enter code here` </ScrollView>
```